# Question can be submitted without review by pressing Enter in the tags bar

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

Steps to reproduce:

1. Ask a new question.
2. Fill valid title and body of the question.
3. Add at least one tag.
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. The question get submitted, without the expected Review Question step.

Can this be avoided?

Comment: though this helps while editing posts later on.. when a post is missing tags, add some tags. hit enter and you're done. Improve title, hit enter & you're done.

Answer (score 11):

This should now be fixed. Hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the tag box should take you to the Review Question step instead of submitting the post. Thanks for the report!

Comment: [Please bring back this very useful feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350814/submitting-a-question-directly-when-there-is-no-feedback)