# Bug when trying to submit a question

Tags: bug, status-completed, asking-questions

I ran into this issue while trying to submit this question on travel.stackexchange.com:

[Traveling International - Are the airports (airliners) communicating with the medical offices?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/158728/traveling-international-are-the-airports-airliners-communicating-with-the-me)

I was able to publish it by viewing the HTML content on the button and getting rid of the `disable` property on the button. Otherwise I could not publish the question.

I tried again to just do a test and the same thing happens. I ask a question, add the tags and the system tells me to review my question and says "Your question is ready to publish!" yet the button to submit is disabled.

I'm on the latest version of Google Chrome:

[image]

It does not happen to this site, but it happens on *travel.stackexchange.com*.

Comment: Duplicate of [Ask question post button remains disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350772/ask-question-post-button-remains-disabled). Also, please choose a title that summarizes the issue. “Bug when trying to submit a question” doesn’t tell us anything.

Comment: @user289905 - There is no answer only a question in the link you posted - and its definitely an issue as I ran into this and had to right click the button and remove the `disabled` property.

Comment: @user289905 - the title fits perfectly - theres a bug when I try to submit a question.

Comment: _“There is no answer only a question in the link you posted”_ — That is irrelevant. The bug has already been reported. It doesn’t need to be reported again.

Comment: @user289905 - good so merge this into that.

Comment: _“the title fits perfectly”_ — The title also fits thousands of other potential issues “perfectly”. Your title harms searchability.

Comment: @user289905 - so fix it?  This is a public site that allows you to edit where you see fit.  Don't complain make it an opportunity.

Comment: Do you have any userscripts, ad blockers or virus scanners running?

Comment: No No No No No No