# Publish question button is disabled

Tags: bug, tags, design, asking-questions

When trying to publish questions on Stack Exchange sites I am seeing the follow behavior after entering the question tags and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

The Post Question button is disabled and not clickable. If I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> one more time, the question is published.

But the behavior is buggy and inconsistent . Sometimes it shows a popup asking if I want to discard the draft, and since I was used to pressing <kbd>enter</kbd> twice, I lose the content that I entered.

> [image]

---

As per [Question can be submitted without review by pressing Enter in the tags bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/347241/205508)

> Hitting Enter on the tag box should take you to the Review Question step instead of submitting the post. Thanks for the report!

But currently the button is disabled or the discard draft appears and content is lost.

Comment: Being able to post a question by pressing enter in the tags bar was a bug (unfortunately) https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/347241/question-can-be-submitted-without-review-by-pressing-enter-in-the-tags-bar

Comment: @Luuklag In any case, the button should not be disabled.

Comment: Also posted on AU meta a couple of weeks ago but didn't get much attention:  https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19210/publish-question-button-is-disabled

Comment: @MarkKirby Initially I thought it's specific to AskUbuntu, but then, I noticed it on the other sites. It's related to pressing Enter in the tags input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be fixed now.

When pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, the button is not disabled anymore.

Comment: It is solved by this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/350772/ask-question-post-button-remains-disabled/353280#353280